# office365 SMTP working on local host but "cannot send to all reciepeints" error on host server

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, smtp, office365

office365 SMTP working on localhost but "cannot send to all reciepeints" error on host server.

emails are correct , have checked all things I found in internet but still no resolution. Can anybody help